# How can you make the Lenovo "utility button" behave like a normal back button?

Tags: linux, mouse, cinnamon, lenovo

I recently purchased a [Lenovo Go](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/fi/en/accessories/acc500205) wireless mouse, because I specifically wanted to avoid having to use a USB-C-to-USB-A dongle with my laptop. This mouse is one of the few mice I am aware which is using a USB-C wireless receiver instead of a traditional USB-A one, which felt kind of nice.

Now, there is only one major problem: the mouse has a particularly odd "utility button" on its left side (described in the Setup Poster mentioned on the previous link; direct link: https://download.lenovo.com/consumer/options/sp41c21213.pdf). This button makes it possible to do all kinds of things like back, forward, change volume, do special things during Teams calls, etc...

There's only a slight catch. This forces the "back" operation to use *two button clicks* instead of a single one. First one click on Utility button, the one click on the Left mouse button. This is, quite frankly, rather annoying since Back is something I do much more than these other operations.

Is there any way to reprogram this "utility button" to be just a normal "back" button (4th mouse button) instead? I'm guessing this *might* be available in the "Lenovo Go Central" (the software for this mouse) but it's Windows-only and I'm using the mouse with Linux (using the Cinnamon desktop). But if anyone has it installed and can confirm "yes, this can be used to reprogram the button like this", this would still be semi-useful information.

Comment: Hmm Lenovo are not spending money on Technical Authors or if they are they are not publishing on their sites. So Best suggestion is beg, borrow or steal a windows **64 bit** and install the go utility software then see what it offers as my kit cant run it either, but then I dont have that type of mouse to try on local Windows 64. I suspect if it is programmable storage it is likely to need reset on battery change but could be wrong either way  (eeprom or die on off switch). Can you run Wine in 64bit mode for testing the utility ? https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=383568

Comment: There are utilities such as free X-Mouse Button Control, https://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/xmousebuttoncontrol.htm, that remap mouse controls, just as AHK remaps keyboard. It may take some effort on your part to find to which button the "utility button" corresponds.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik that utility is the one I recommend for Windows control However AFAIK is only "Running" in Windows Desktop "Run Time" and the usage here is Mint so unlikely it will monitor Linux Apps ?? The Question is asking can the button assignment be stored in the Mouse which is possible but unknown without ANY Lenovo documentation / HELP unless stored in the Windows App so if you can see from any source where the assignments are stored, your a better detective than the OP and me. **@ Per** either email Lenovo or plug the mouse into Windows Go and try to see if it survives on off switch!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @KJ and DrMoishePippik (can only ping one of you unfortunately). I do have a virtualized Windows 11 installed.. I guess it could try installing the utility there to see what we can do with it, but I probably have to use some "USB passthrough" to be able to get the Lenovo Windows software to detect the mouse? Anyway, worth giving a look. I'll post back here if/when I give it a look.